# Query only returning 7 of 9 expected values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble getting a sql php/pdo statement to return to values from the below query. The query returns 7 values but I expect 9. When I do a variable dump, I see it is ignoring the values for news.ID and stories.ID.

I have tables called news and stories. I can't tell if my problem is with my join or that I am using $ID for each in the bindparam that is messing it up (and what should I use instead if so since they both have the column name ID in their respective tables).

```
$results2 = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.ID,
stories.SID,
news.ID,
news.WID,
news.text,
news.approved,
news.position
FROM news
LEFT JOIN stories on news.SID = stories.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON news.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID) AND (news.approved = 'N') 
AND (news.position= $cont) order by news.WID asc limit 10");

$results2->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':display_name', $display_name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$results2->bindParam(':stories.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':stories.SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results2->bindParam(':news.WID', $WID, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$results2->bindParam(':news.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$results2->bindParam(':approved', $f = N, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$results2->bindParam(':position', $cont, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$results2->execute();
$row2 = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here is the var dump results:

> array(7) { 
>      ["ID"]=> string(1) “1″
>    >    ["display_name"]=> string(9) “admin” 
>      ["SID"]=> string(2) “77″
>    >    ["WID"]=> string(3) “236″
>    >    ["text"]=> string(32) “sfkjsdjsdlfjsdkfjksdjfdsjfksfdks”
>    >    ["approved"]=> string(1) “N” 
>      ["position"]=> string(2) “13″
>       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a difference between the IDs,

change it to something like this

```
$results2 = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID AS ID1,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.ID AS ID2,
stories.SID,
news.ID AS ID3,
.....");
```

Because you have 3 ID's mysql will only show one

Comment: Do I also name the variables $ID1 and $ID2 in the bindparam?

Comment: No you don't, but I would advice you to better form you queries. I find them confusion to read. If you use bindparam it's mostly bad practice to include variables into you query (unless they are defined in your code and not by the user).